# Magento extra role field

Tags: magento

I have added an extra field in the `admin_role` table in magento called `limit_products`. I have also added an extra field into the magento backend, and using the `admin_permissions_role_prepare_save` event I set this field to either 1 or 0, using the function below. However, it doesn't seem to want to save this field at all. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I even tried setting the field in `RoleController.php` (where the other fields are set), but no luck. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
public function adminPermissionsRolePrepareSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $role = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
    //fb($request);
    $role->setLimitProducts((bool)$request->getPost('limit_products', false));
    return $this;
}
```

EDIT: I just realised I forgot to mention that `$request->getPost('limit_products', false);` does return the right value, it's just the `$role->setLimitProducts();` isn't saving it. Also when I do `$role->getLimitProducts();` it does return the right value.

Comment: Have you checked the database to see if the value is making it in or not?

Comment: Yes, so that's really the main problem, it's not saving it to the database, however, if it do `$role->getLimitProducts();` just before the return statement, it seems to set it properly.